# Binding to a filtered observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an observable collection of type `A`.

Class `A` contains an enum - `IsWhite`.

My observable collection is called `ACollection`.

I also have 2 datagrids, one that will have an `itemssource` bound to `ACollection` where the `A` items have `IsWhite` set to false, the other datagrid which is bound to the same collection but with `IsWhite` set to true.

How can I achieve this?

The collection is declared as follows;

`ObservableCollection<A> ACollection = new ObservableCollection<A>;`

and the class

```
public class A
{
    IsWhite isWhiteEnum { get; set; } = IsWhite.False;
}
```

I want one datagrid `itemssource` to bind to `ACollection` populating the items where `IsWhite` is `False` and the other datagrid `itemssource` to bind to `ACollection` popualting items where `IsWhite` is `True`.

Comment: Can you please show us what you have already tried, what isn't working and expected output as well as a simple example for us to replicate? We would be able to help you further if you can provide a minimal example.

Comment: I updated everything. Basically I have 2 datagrids, and i want them to use the same itemssource but one with filtered out items using an enum

Comment: I have a sample illustrates 2 views on one collection. Wrote an article as well.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26673.wpf-collectionview-tips.aspx

Comment: lol I need to improve my Googling skills which have always been poor. I am using MVVM with no code-behind so not sure if the examples help... Can I declare an `ICollectionView` with a new filtered list applied?

Comment: The sample is mvvm.

Comment: Maybe what I should say is rather than writing code-behind, where is the XAML that links the itemssource to the filtered collection? I'm probably just blind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a precis of the relevent parts of the article here:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26673.wpf-collectionview-tips.aspx

You don't want to filter the default view of a collection because that way your filter would apply to both datagrids.

This bit of code gets two independent views:

```
PeopleView = (CollectionView)new CollectionViewSource { Source = People }.View;
LevelsPeopleView = (CollectionView)new CollectionViewSource { Source = People }.View;
```

People is an observablecollection of person.

Both those views are collectionviews, eg.

```
 public CollectionView LevelsPeopleView { get; set; }
```

The views are bound in TwoCollectionViews.xaml eg

```
    <DataGrid ....
              ItemsSource="{Binding PeopleView}"
```

And the article illustrates various filters such as the msdn approach:

```
private void ShowOnlyBargainsFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
AuctionItem product = e.Item as AuctionItem;
if (product != null)
{
    // Filter out products with price 25 or above
    if (product.CurrentPrice < 25)
    {
        e.Accepted = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Accepted = false;
    }
}
}
```

Or much more sophisticated approaches.

You set a filter:

```
            LevelsPeopleView.Filter = FirstOfLevel_Filter;
```

If the view has already grabbed the data out that collectionview then nothing will happen. You need to also do

```
         LevelsPeopleView.Refresh();
```

This sort of filtering is quite inefficient and linq is better at large datasets. Still better is small datasets. Unless your users really really like scrolling.

Comment: Thanks Andy, this helps (I'm not an expert at WPF yet so I got a bit lost with the CollectionView malarkey as I've not had to use it). This'll definitely help. Is there no way to avoid having to call `Refresh()` when necessary?

Comment: I'm getting an error when I write `ListModels.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(ShowOnlyModels);` for example. It says `Cannot implicitly convert type FilterEventHandler to Predicate<object>`... the declaration of `ShowOnlyModels` is `private void ShowOnlyModels(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)` :\

Comment: You set it Filter =. No +. See above